# sql.QueryContext in sql go package convert table name to lowercase (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, go

I have table `Role` in Postgresql

I write sql query  `SELECT * FROM public.Role WHERE login=Bob`.

Then I try to execute this with [sql.QueryContext](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.QueryContext)

But I got error `relation "public.role" does not exist`

So, this function transform table name to lowercase and can't find it. Are there any ways to solve this problem, excluding create new database `role`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL is a bit weird when it comes to table names if you created it with double quotes.  For example:

```
db=> create table Blah (id int null);
CREATE TABLE
db=> select * from blah;
 id 
----
(0 rows)

db=> select * from Blah;
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

ok, no problems.  Now, use quotes:

```
db=> create table "Blah" (id int null);
CREATE TABLE
db=> select * from Blah;
ERROR:  relation "blah" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from Blah;
                      ^
db=> select * from blah;
ERROR:  relation "blah" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from blah;

db=> select * from "Blah";
 id 
----
(0 rows)

db=> select * from "blah";
ERROR:  relation "blah" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "blah";
```

In the second case, because double quotes were used you need to pay attention to the upper/lower case of the table name **and** you need to use the double quotes to find the table.

I'd strongly recommend using lower case table names without the double quotes and the underbar character for separating words (i.e. `role_mappings` instead of RoleMappings).  Most ORM systems do the right thing with the underbar and your code will be portable to multiple database environments too.

Lastly, while the word "Role" is not a reserved SQL key word, it is used in PostgreSQL and other databases in SQL syntax.  I've spent far too much time looking for weird errors when I was using something that is "sorta reserved".

Comment: Thanks! `public."Role"` worked